# How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?

Tags: curl, time, upload, download, measure

I have a web service that receives data in JSON format, processes the data, and then returns the result to the requester.

I want to measure the request, response, and total time using `cURL`.

My example request looks like:

```
curl -X POST -d @file server:port
```

and I currently measure this using the `time` command in Linux:

```
time curl -X POST -d @file server:port
```

The time command only measures *total* time, though - which isn't quite what I am looking for.

Is there any way to measure request and response times using `cURL`?

Answer (score 2633, accepted):

*From this brilliant blog post...  https://blog.josephscott.org/2011/10/14/timing-details-with-curl/*

cURL supports formatted output for the details of the request (see [the cURL manpage for details](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), under `-w, –write-out <format>`). For our purposes we’ll focus just on the timing details that are provided. Times below are in **seconds**.

1. **Create a new file, `curl-format.txt`, and paste in:**

   ```
        time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}s\n
           time_connect:  %{time_connect}s\n
        time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}s\n
       time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}s\n
          time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}s\n
     time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}s\n
                        ----------\n
             time_total:  %{time_total}s\n
   ```
2. **Make a request:**

   ```
    curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "http://wordpress.com/"
   ```

   Or on Windows, it's...

   ```
    curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o NUL -s "http://wordpress.com/"
   ```

### What this does:

`-w "@curl-format.txt"` tells cURL to use our format file
`-o /dev/null` redirects the output of the request to /dev/null
`-s`
tells cURL not to show a progress meter
`"http://wordpress.com/"` is
the URL we are requesting. Use quotes particularly if your URL has "&" query string parameters

### And here is what you get back:

```
   time_namelookup:  0.001s
      time_connect:  0.037s
   time_appconnect:  0.000s
  time_pretransfer:  0.037s
     time_redirect:  0.000s
time_starttransfer:  0.092s
                   ----------
        time_total:  0.164s
```

I have not yet seen an option to output the results in microseconds, but if you're aware of one, post in the comments below.

### Make a Linux/Mac shortcut (alias)

```
alias curltime="curl -w \"@$HOME/.curl-format.txt\" -o /dev/null -s "
```

Then you can simply call...

```
curltime wordpress.org
```

*Thanks to commenter Pete Doyle!*

### Make a Linux/Mac stand-alone script

This script does not require a separate `.txt` file to contain the formatting.

Create a new file, `curltime`, somewhere in your executable path, and paste in:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -w @- -o /dev/null -s "$@" <<'EOF'
    time_namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}\n
       time_connect:  %{time_connect}\n
    time_appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}\n
   time_pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}\n
      time_redirect:  %{time_redirect}\n
 time_starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}\n
                    ----------\n
         time_total:  %{time_total}\n
EOF
```

Then call it the same way as the alias:

```
curltime wordpress.org
```

### Make a Windows shortcut (aka BAT file)

Create a new text file called `curltime.bat` in the same folder as `curl.exe` and `curl-format.txt`, and paste in the following line:

```
curl -w "@%~dp0curl-format.txt" -o NUL -s %*
```

Then from the command line you can simply call:

```
curltime wordpress.org
```

(Make sure the folder is listed in your Windows `PATH` variable to be able to use the command from any folder.)

Comment: In the windows BAT file it only sends the first parameter, change to this to pass all parameters and to disable echo the command it self: `@curl -w "@%~dp0curl-format.txt" -o NUL -s %*` Great answer

Comment: For Linux, I made a dotfile and an alias and it seems to work well:
`alias curltime="curl -w \"@$HOME/.curl-format.txt\" -o NUL -s "`. Likely works on MacOS, too.

Comment: For zsh I you can use this alias with arguments: `alias curltime='curl -w "@$HOME/bin/curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s $1'` which makes you able to do `curltime http://someurl.com` :)

Comment: Would it be possible to run it multiple times to a have an average result?

Comment: not working on win11

Answer (score 360):

**Option 1:** to measure `total time`:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w 'Total: %{time_total}s\n'  https://www.google.com
```

Sample output:

```sh
Total: 0.441094s
```

**Option 2:** to get `time to establish connection`, `time to first byte (TTFB)` and `total time`:

```
curl -o /dev/null -s -w 'Establish Connection: %{time_connect}s\nTTFB: %{time_starttransfer}s\nTotal: %{time_total}s\n'  https://www.google.com
```

Sample output:

```sh
Establish Connection: 0.020033s
TTFB: 0.417907s
Total: 0.435486s
```

Ref: [Get response time with curl](https://viewsby.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/get-response-time-with-curl/)

Comment: Cool, but it seems cannot check bad URL.

Answer (score 260):

Here is the answer:

```
curl -X POST -d @file server:port -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}
```

All of the variables used with `-w` can be found in `man curl`.

Comment: It is better for user experience to add new lines: `"\n%{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}\n"`

Comment: For me it was not working without quotes. I would suggest adding quotes while specifying the format
/h/a/c/haproxy # ❯❯❯ curl -w "%{time_total}\n" http://google.com -o /dev/null -s
0.055

Comment: @Geek It generally makes sense to show errors when operating in silent mode (`-sS`).

Answer (score 89):

The following is inspired by Simon's answer. It's self-contained (doesn't require a separate format file), which makes it great for inclusion into `.bashrc`.

```sh
curl_time() {
    curl -so /dev/null -w "\
   namelookup:  %{time_namelookup}s\n\
      connect:  %{time_connect}s\n\
   appconnect:  %{time_appconnect}s\n\
  pretransfer:  %{time_pretransfer}s\n\
     redirect:  %{time_redirect}s\n\
starttransfer:  %{time_starttransfer}s\n\
-------------------------\n\
        total:  %{time_total}s\n" "$@"
}
```

Futhermore, it should work with all arguments that `curl` normally takes, since the `"$@"` just passes them through. For example, you can do:

```sh
curl_time -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key": "val"}' https://postman-echo.com/post
```

Output:

```sh
   namelookup:  0,125000s
      connect:  0,250000s
   appconnect:  0,609000s
  pretransfer:  0,609000s
     redirect:  0,000000s
starttransfer:  0,719000s
-------------------------
        total:  0,719000s
```

Answer (score 59):

A shortcut you can add to your .bashrc etc, based on other answers here:

```
function perf {
  curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{time_connect} + %{time_starttransfer} = %{time_total}\n" "$1"
}
```

Usage:

```
> perf stackoverflow.com
0.521 + 0.686 = 1.290
```

Comment: I use a variation that displays the number of bytes downloaded during the measured time:
`curl -o /dev/null -s -w "time_total: %{time_total} sec\nsize_download: %{size_download} bytes\n" https://www.google.com`

Answer (score 57):

If you want to analyze or summarize the latency you can try apache bench:

```
ab -n [number of samples] [url]
```

For example:

```
ab -n 100 http://www.google.com/
```

It will show:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1757674 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.google.com (be patient).....done


Server Software:        gws
Server Hostname:        www.google.com
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        12419 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   10.700 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        97
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 97, Exceptions: 0)
Total transferred:      1331107 bytes
HTML transferred:       1268293 bytes
Requests per second:    9.35 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       107.004 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       107.004 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          121.48 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       20   22   0.8     22      26
Processing:    59   85 108.7     68     911
Waiting:       59   85 108.7     67     910
Total:         80  107 108.8     90     932

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     90
  66%     91
  75%     93
  80%     95
  90%    105
  95%    111
  98%    773
  99%    932
 100%    932 (longest request)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. And `ab` handily accepts a lot of the same flags as `curl` e.g. `-H` for headers. I used this command to benchmark the response times of a third party API (supplying the bearer token in an Authorization header). Worked brilliantly.

Answer (score 40):

You can use `curl -v --trace-time` to add timestamps to the trace/verbose output. This must be done in verbose mode or trace mode to do anything.

Comment: This is awesome! It helped me diagnose a problem with my IPv6. I couldn't see this information from the top-voted answer. 

Answer (score 38):

Another way is configuring `~/.curlrc` like this

```
-w "\n\n==== cURL measurements stats ====\ntotal: %{time_total} seconds \nsize: %{size_download} bytes \ndnslookup: %{time_namelookup} seconds \nconnect: %{time_connect} seconds \nappconnect: %{time_appconnect} seconds \nredirect: %{time_redirect} seconds \npretransfer: %{time_pretransfer} seconds \nstarttransfer: %{time_starttransfer} seconds \ndownloadspeed: %{speed_download} byte/sec \nuploadspeed: %{speed_upload} byte/sec \n\n"
```

So the output of `curl` is

```
❯❯ curl -I https://google.com
HTTP/2 301
location: https://www.google.com/
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 08:02:43 GMT
expires: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 08:02:43 GMT
cache-control: public, max-age=2592000
server: gws
content-length: 220
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39"



==== cURL measurements stats ====
total: 0.211117 seconds
size: 0 bytes
dnslookup: 0.067179 seconds
connect: 0.098817 seconds
appconnect: 0.176232 seconds
redirect: 0.000000 seconds
pretransfer: 0.176438 seconds
starttransfer: 0.209634 seconds
downloadspeed: 0.000 byte/sec
uploadspeed: 0.000 byte/sec
```

Comment: Would you show me the reference to more detail documents about that?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm details in curl official book https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-writeout.html

Comment: Oh this is a great solution, works well for i.e. the nvim-rest plugin (which uses cURL under the hood)

Answer (score 21):

Another option that is perhaps the *simplest* one in terms of the command line is adding the built-in `--trace-time` option:

```
curl -X POST -d @file server:port --trace-time
```

Even though it technically does not output the timings of the various steps as requested by the OP, it does display the timestamps for *all* steps of the request as shown below. Using this, you can (fairly easily) calculate how long each step has taken.

```
$ curl https://www.google.com --trace-time -v -o /dev/null
13:29:11.148734 * Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     013:29:11.149958 *   Trying 172.217.20.36...
13:29:11.149993 * TCP_NODELAY set
13:29:11.163177 * Connected to www.google.com (172.217.20.36) port 443 (#0)
13:29:11.164768 * ALPN, offering h2
13:29:11.164804 * ALPN, offering http/1.1
13:29:11.164833 * successfully set certificate verify locations:
13:29:11.164863 *   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
13:29:11.165046 } [5 bytes data]
13:29:11.165099 * (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
13:29:11.165128 } [512 bytes data]
13:29:11.189518 * (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
13:29:11.189537 { [100 bytes data]
13:29:11.189628 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
13:29:11.189658 { [2104 bytes data]
13:29:11.190243 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
13:29:11.190277 { [115 bytes data]
13:29:11.190507 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
13:29:11.190539 { [4 bytes data]
13:29:11.190770 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
13:29:11.190797 } [37 bytes data]
13:29:11.190890 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
13:29:11.190915 } [1 bytes data]
13:29:11.191023 * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
13:29:11.191053 } [16 bytes data]
13:29:11.204324 * TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
13:29:11.204358 { [16 bytes data]
13:29:11.204417 * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
13:29:11.204451 * ALPN, server accepted to use h2
13:29:11.204483 * Server certificate:
13:29:11.204520 *  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=www.google.com
13:29:11.204555 *  start date: Oct  2 07:29:00 2018 GMT
13:29:11.204585 *  expire date: Dec 25 07:29:00 2018 GMT
13:29:11.204623 *  subjectAltName: host "www.google.com" matched cert's "www.google.com"
13:29:11.204663 *  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
13:29:11.204701 *  SSL certificate verify ok.
13:29:11.204754 * Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
13:29:11.204795 * Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
13:29:11.204840 * Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
13:29:11.204881 } [5 bytes data]
13:29:11.204983 * Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55846ef24520)
13:29:11.205034 } [5 bytes data]
13:29:11.205104 > GET / HTTP/2
13:29:11.205104 > Host: www.google.com
13:29:11.205104 > User-Agent: curl/7.61.0
13:29:11.205104 > Accept: */*
13:29:11.205104 > 
13:29:11.218116 { [5 bytes data]
13:29:11.218173 * Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
13:29:11.218211 } [5 bytes data]
13:29:11.251936 < HTTP/2 200 
13:29:11.251962 < date: Fri, 19 Oct 2018 10:29:11 GMT
13:29:11.251998 < expires: -1
13:29:11.252046 < cache-control: private, max-age=0
13:29:11.252085 < content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
13:29:11.252119 < p3p: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
13:29:11.252160 < server: gws
13:29:11.252198 < x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
13:29:11.252228 < x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
13:29:11.252262 < set-cookie: 1P_JAR=2018-10-19-10; expires=Sun, 18-Nov-2018 10:29:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
13:29:11.252297 < set-cookie: NID=141=pzXxp1jrJmLwFVl9bLMPFdGCtG8ySQKxB2rlDWgerrKJeXxfdmB1HhJ1UXzX-OaFQcnR1A9LKYxi__PWMigjMBQHmI3xkU53LI_TsYRbkMNJNdxs-caQQ7fEcDGE694S; expires=Sat, 20-Apr-2019 10:29:11 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
13:29:11.252336 < alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35"
13:29:11.252368 < accept-ranges: none
13:29:11.252408 < vary: Accept-Encoding
13:29:11.252438 < 
13:29:11.252473 { [5 bytes data]
100 12215    0 12215    0     0   112k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  112k
13:29:11.255674 * Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact
```

Comment: This is actually a great answer which is probably going to fit most of the use-cases people here are looking for. The other answers are great for thorough, in-depth solutions, but this is good for quickly checking round-trip times.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisVandevelde. Yeah, I was aware that there was "something" like this (had used this parameter before), then I googled my way to this SO post and found the more sophisticated form, but... I had a feeling there was another way also. :) Like you say, it's kind of neat in its simplicity and is sometimes well enough for simpler use cases.

Comment: See the timestamps to the left of each step. I overlooked it and was looking for an actual explicit output.

Answer (score 18):

Hey is better than Apache Bench, has fewer issues with SSL

```
./hey https://google.com -more
Summary:
  Total:    3.0960 secs
  Slowest:  1.6052 secs
  Fastest:  0.4063 secs
  Average:  0.6773 secs
  Requests/sec: 64.5992

Response time histogram:
  0.406 [1] |
  0.526 [142]   |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  0.646 [1] |
  0.766 [6] |∎∎
  0.886 [0] |
  1.006 [0] |
  1.126 [0] |
  1.246 [12]    |∎∎∎
  1.365 [32]    |∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  1.485 [5] |∎
  1.605 [1] |

Latency distribution:
  10% in 0.4265 secs
  25% in 0.4505 secs
  50% in 0.4838 secs
  75% in 1.2181 secs
  90% in 1.2869 secs
  95% in 1.3384 secs
  99% in 1.4085 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:    0.1150 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.4849 secs
  DNS-lookup:    0.0032 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0319 secs
  req write:     0.0001 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0007 secs
  resp wait:     0.2068 secs, 0.1690 secs, 0.4906 secs
  resp read:     0.0117 secs, 0.0011 secs, 0.2375 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 200 responses
```

#### References

- https://github.com/rakyll/hey

Answer (score 13):

### Generic solution to measuring command execution time

#### Linux / Mac OS / Unix

On Linux you can measure the time taken for a command to execute with the `time` command

```
time curl https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat
```

Output:

```
ect...
</body>
</html>

real    0m0.565s
user    0m0.011s
sys     0m0.024s
```

Here the overall time / response time is the `real` time.

This solution is generic and should work with any Unix command

```
time sleep 5
```

Output:

```
real    0m5.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys 0m0.000s
```

#### Windows Powershell

You can use [*Measure-Command*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Bash one-liner to hit the same server repeatedly:

```
for i in {1..1000}; do curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{time_total}\n" http://server/get_things; done
```

Answer (score 6):

I made a friendly formatter for sniffing curl requests to help with debugging ( see comments for usage ).  It contains's every known output parameter you can write out in an easy to read format.

https://gist.github.com/manifestinteractive/ce8dec10dcb4725b8513

Answer (score 6):

here is the string you can use with `-w`, contains all options that `curl -w` supports.

```
{"contentType":"%{content_type}","filenameEffective":"%{filename_effective}","ftpEntryPath":"%{ftp_entry_path}","httpCode":"%{http_code}","httpConnect":"%{http_connect}","httpVersion":"%{http_version}","localIp":"%{local_ip}","localPort":"%{local_port}","numConnects":"%{num_connects}","numRedirects":"%{num_redirects}","proxySslVerifyResult":"%{proxy_ssl_verify_result}","redirectUrl":"%{redirect_url}","remoteIp":"%{remote_ip}","remotePort":"%{remote_port}","scheme":"%{scheme}","size":{"download":"%{size_download}","header":"%{size_header}","request":"%{size_request}","upload":"%{size_upload}"},"speed":{"download":"%{speed_download}","upload":"%{speed_upload}"},"sslVerifyResult":"%{ssl_verify_result}","time":{"appconnect":"%{time_appconnect}","connect":"%{time_connect}","namelookup":"%{time_namelookup}","pretransfer":"%{time_pretransfer}","redirect":"%{time_redirect}","starttransfer":"%{time_starttransfer}","total":"%{time_total}"},"urlEffective":"%{url_effective}"}
```

outputs JSON.

Comment: Prepending `\n` helps separate the timing when body doesn't end with newline: `curl -w '\n{"contentType":"..."}...`

Answer (score 6):

This is a modified version of Simons answer which makes the multi-lined output a single line. It also introduces the current timestamp so it's easier to follow each line of output.

***Sample format fle***

```
$ cat time-format.txt
time_namelookup:%{time_namelookup} time_connect:%{time_connect} time_appconnect:%{time_appconnect} time_pretransfer:%{time_pretransfer} time_redirect:%{time_redirect} time_starttransfer:%{time_starttransfer} time_total:%{time_total}\n
```

***example cmd***

```
$ while [ 1 ];do echo -n "$(date) - " ; curl -w @time-format.txt -o /dev/null -s https://myapp.mydom.com/v1/endpt-http; sleep 1; done | grep -v time_total:0
```

***results***

```
Mon Dec 16 17:51:47 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:0.172 time_pretransfer:0.172 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.666 time_total:1.666
Mon Dec 16 17:51:50 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:0.175 time_pretransfer:0.175 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:3.794 time_total:3.795
Mon Dec 16 17:51:55 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.017 time_appconnect:0.175 time_pretransfer:0.175 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.971 time_total:1.971
Mon Dec 16 17:51:58 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.014 time_appconnect:0.173 time_pretransfer:0.173 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.161 time_total:1.161
Mon Dec 16 17:52:00 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:0.166 time_pretransfer:0.167 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.434 time_total:1.434
Mon Dec 16 17:52:02 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:0.177 time_pretransfer:0.177 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:5.119 time_total:5.119
Mon Dec 16 17:52:08 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.014 time_appconnect:0.172 time_pretransfer:0.172 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:30.185 time_total:30.185
Mon Dec 16 17:52:39 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.014 time_appconnect:0.164 time_pretransfer:0.164 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:30.175 time_total:30.176
Mon Dec 16 17:54:28 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:3.191 time_pretransfer:3.191 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:3.212 time_total:3.212
Mon Dec 16 17:56:08 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:1.184 time_pretransfer:1.184 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.215 time_total:1.215
Mon Dec 16 18:00:24 UTC 2019 - time_namelookup:0.004 time_connect:0.015 time_appconnect:0.181 time_pretransfer:0.181 time_redirect:0.000 time_starttransfer:1.267 time_total:1.267
```

I used the above to catch slow responses on the above endpoint.