# Add request timestamp with CURL

Tags: linux, apache, curl, logging, get

I'm working in a small LINUX project to calculate requests latency with CURL and a remote website.

So I made a shell script to send automatically GET requests to the remote Apache Webserver. And while accessing Apache's access.log I only find the time when requests from CURL were received by apache only.

Is it possible to also send the date of the CURL request to apache server? (Timestamp)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding and you're wanting to measure latency client-side where curl is, you can use `--write-out`
[How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl)

Server-side, unless someone customized the log, every hit to the server should log both date and time in the access_log

```
::1 - - [25/Mar/2016:22:37:54 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 38
```

EDIT:

Okay, given what you want.. not sure what it would show, since requests take portions of seconds, and clocks on different computers aren't necessarily the same. Nevertheless, to send the client's date with the curl request, you can capture the timestamp and send it as part of a custom user-agent using the `-A` option.

e.g. if in a unix bash shell that supports nanoseconds

```
curl -A `date +"[mycurltime:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3N]"` "http://hostname/etc"
```

results in...

```
your.ip.addy - - [26/Mar/2016:16:52:54 -0700] "GET /etc HTTP/1.1" 200 7502 "-" "[mycurltime:2016-03-26T16:52:54.437]"
```

Comment: Actually I want to send the request date to Apache in a way I would find something like this in the access.log                                                                                     ::1 - - [25/Mar/2016:22:37:54 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 38 <Date of when the CURL request was sent>