# Can't get Feign Client to work for a basic example

Tags: rest, spring-boot, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Can't get Feign Client to work. First tried with POST. Kept running into errors related to Encoder/Decoder saying type is not right.
Then found an example on github to call simple GET API finally and decided to give it a shot.
Still fails

On Github and online, I am seeing multiple versions of Feign Client
Spring-Cloud, OpenFeign, Netflix.feign having different versions.
Could anyone describe what's the best and stable Feign client one should use for production?

```
package com.paa.controllers;

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@FeignClient (name="test-service",url="https://www.reddit.com/r")
public interface GetFeignClient {

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/java.json")
     public String posts();
}

Controller:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/some/api")
public class TestWLCController {

  @Autowired
  private GetFeignClient getFeignClient;

  .. some stuff


    @RequestMapping(value="/postSomething",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Configures something",
            notes = "basic rest controller for testing feign")

    public ResponseEntity<SomeResponse> feignPost(
            UriComponentsBuilder builder,
            @ApiParam(name = "myRequest", 
            value = "request for configuring something", 
            required = true)
            @Valid @RequestBody SomeRequest someRequest) {

        String resp = null;
        try {
            resp = getFeignClient.posts();
        } catch (Exception er) {
            er.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Application:

Tried all possible permutations of annotations thinking it would resolve AutoWire stuff but still fails

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients

//@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableFeignClients
//@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {"com.paa.xenia.controllers", "com.paa.xenia.services"})
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {

        return application.sources(XeniaServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

> 2016-07-20 18:15:42.406[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m32749[0;39m
>   [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m
>   [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
>   Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testWLCController': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.paa.controllers.GetFeignClient
>   com.paa.controllers.TestWLCController.gfClient; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'com.aa..controllers.GetFeignClient':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]     at
>   com.paa.ServiceApplication.main(ServiceApplication.java:44) [bin/:na]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private com.paa.controllers.GetFeignClient
>   com.paa.controllers.TestWLCController.gfClient; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'com.paa.controllers.GetFeignClient':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]   ... 17 com.n frames
>   omitted

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you eventually figured it out yourself, but for the sake of others who might stumble across this thread, below is a working example of what you were trying to do. I'll first point out a few things that are incorrect, or at least, not desired in your code, then show my code that works.

1. You should try not to use the `url` attribute. Instead, set up a list of servers using `<feign client name>.ribbon.listOfServers` in `bootstrap.yml` (or `bootstrap.properties`). This allows for client side load balancing because `listOfServers` can be a comma-separated list.
2. Using Ribbon for HTTPS connections, you need to specify two things that you don't need for HTTP connections. The port, which is part of the `listOfServers` and `<feign client name>.ribbon.IsSecure: true`. Without the port, the connection is made to port 80 and without the `IsSecure`, HTTP is used.
3. Testing using `curl`, I found that Reddit takes a **very** long time to respond. See this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl) for details of how to break down the total time taken by the request-response cycle.

   ```
   $ curl -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "https://www.reddit.com/r/java/top.json?count=1"
   { [2759 bytes data]
   * Connection #0 to host www.reddit.com left intact
   time_namelookup:     0.527
   time_connect:        0.577
   time_appconnect:     0.758
   time_pretransfer:    0.758
   time_redirect:       0.000
   time_starttransfer: 11.189
                     ----------
   time_total:         11.218
   ```

According the Netflix [Wiki](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Getting-Started), the default read and connect timeouts are 3000 milliseconds, so you will always timeout unless you change those.

4. You may have noticed that I specified a `User-Agent` header in the `curl` request. That's because Reddis seems to be very picky about that and if not specified, returns a HTTP 429 "Too many requests" most of the times. They don't return a `Retry-After` header in the response so there's no telling how long you need to wait before making another request.
5. Spring Cloud Netflix as well as Netflix Feign is open source, so some (a lot of) patience and debugging skills come really handy.

*"Talk is cheap. Show me the code." (Torvalds, Linus (2000-08-25))*.

I generated a Gradle app using the excellent [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/) site. Here's a snippet from the `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR3"
    }
}
```

**Feign client**:

```
@FeignClient(name = "reddit")
public interface RedditClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/r/java/top.json?count=1",
            headers = {USER_AGENT + "=Mozilla/5.0", ACCEPT + "=" + APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String posts();
}
```

**Boot Application**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    static class DemoController {
        @Autowired
        private RedditClient redditClient;

        @GetMapping("/posts")
        public String posts() {
            return redditClient.posts();
        }
    }
}
```

**bootstrap.yml**:

```
reddit:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: www.reddit.com:443
    ConnectTimeout: 20000
    ReadTimeout: 20000
    IsSecure: true
hystrix.command.default.execution:
  timeout.enabled: true
  isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 50000
```

**Integration test**:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class DemoApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testGetPosts() {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/posts", String.class);

        HttpStatus statusCode = responseEntity.getStatusCode();
        assertThat(String.format("Actual status code: %d, reason: %s.",
                statusCode.value(), statusCode.getReasonPhrase()),
                statusCode.is2xxSuccessful(), equalTo(true));
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to use Feign successfully although we did not really use 'ribbon'. We used as Rest Client since it is much cleaner. The other lesson we learnt was - for Feign to process headers and intercept responses, one has to implement Decoders for Feign and also have  a Feign Config. I will post code once I get some time.

Comment: The point I tried to clarify was we used Feign without Ribbon. So Ribbon is not mandatory to use Feign ====feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: false
datasource:
  audit:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27019
      database: audit
===

Comment: @Rockoder You were able to make this work. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: @alltej yes was able to make it work though getting code would be bit tricky. Basically, we created a parent module serving as our framework and used Feign there. The module which used Feign did not have to declare Feign explicitly in child classes. Also, spring version is important. We were on 3.5. I learnt from a co-worker when they tried to use a later version, they faced problems and they ended up going back to version we were on to get it working.

Comment: @alltej comments have restriction so I posted answer for you. Hopefully this helps. All essential components/classes skeleton to get it working is there. Let me know if this works. Also, the version 3.5 I mentioned above was wrong by mistake. It is 1.3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

App:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.test.cloud.bookservice.models.Book;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
@EnableFeignClients
public class BookServiceApplication {

    Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BookServiceApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    private StoreClient storeClient;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookServiceApplication.class, args);
    }


    @GetMapping("/book")
    public Book findBook() {
            return this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://stores/book", Book.class);
    }

    @FeignClient(name = "StoreClient", url = "127.0.0.1:8089")
    interface StoreClient {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stores/book", consumes = "application/json")
        Book getBook();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone was interested to find out how did we do it so posting answer for their benefit.

## Parent Module

```
package com.hitech.module.base;

@EnableFeignClients
public abstract class BaseApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
...
..
}

build.gradle:

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}
...
...

dependencies {
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.5.0')
    compile('io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.5.0')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-feign')
```

## Child Module

```
package com.hitech.module.app;

import com.hitech.module.base.BaseApplication;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class, MongoAutoConfiguration.class},
        scanBasePackages = {"com.hitech.module.base", "com.hitech.module.app", })
@EnableFeignClients("com.hitech.module.app.clients")
public class MyServiceApplication extends BaseApplication {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "google";

        LOG.info ("=== Started Orchestration Service ===");
        SpringApplication.run(MyServiceApplication.class, args);


    }
}
```

bootstrap.yml

```
feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: false
datasource:
  audit:
    mongodb:
      host: localhost
      port: 27019
      database: audit
```