# uri module with response times

Tags: url, curl, ansible, response

I'd like to have the response times from sites in Ansible, something along the lines [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl), but in Ansible. I'm using the [URI module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html) but it seems it does not support response times.

I do not like to use the callback plugin with the time profile, because I state multiple url's in a single task.

I see Ansible does not return the values I require, is this something someone has already done?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've created [a whole playbook out of this request](https://github.com/csuka/endpoint_check). The playbook itself includes:

- Check whether URL's are providing status code 200
- Includes the reaction time from the host to the server
- Sending Slack message when failed
- Send the logs to an Elasticsearch server

One could set a cronjob to let the playbook run each x seconds.

Comment: That link now giving a 404 :-(

Comment: Check my GitHub, it’s probably somewhere over there still.