# Ansible - url check for multiple hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am writing the Ansible playbook to check the URL status for multiple IPs from the hosts file, however, it is not working when I am giving input as a group name, but is working for single IP

Here is my playbook,

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "hosts"
      prompt: "Please enter the hosts details"
      private: no
    - name: "port"
      prompt: "Please enter the port"
      private: no
  serial: 1
  tasks:
  - name: check the url http://{{ hosts }}:{{ port }}/test
    uri:
      url: "http://{{ hosts }}:{{ port }}/test"
      follow_redirects: none
      method: GET
    register: _result
    until: _result.status == 200
```

My application is running on below Ips and I want to check the url status for all.

```
[webservers]
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.20
10.10.10.30
10.10.10.40
```

**But it's getting failed with below error.**

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -u test --ask-pass
SSH password:
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
Please enter the hosts details: webservers
Please enter the port: 8080
[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: port

PLAY [webservers] ****************************************************************************> ********************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.10.10.10]

TASK [http://webservers:8080/test]  **********************************************************************
[WARNING]: The value True (type bool) in a string field was converted to u'True' (type string). If this does not look like what
you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.
fatal: [10.10.10.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "failed_when_result": true, "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "http://webservers:8080/test"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************
10.10.10.10             : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can someone please suggest on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63908234/edit) and format it correctly, more specifically the code and output blocks. Read the help on the edit page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I’ve already solved what you’re trying to do, in another question.

Please take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319936/uri-module-with-response-times).

You could edit the provided playbook to match your use-case.

Comment: as per the suggested link, I need to add urls in vars, but I need to check this for 100's of IPs, so in this case, I need to add that many IPs in vars, and I am looking for a better solution, If I give just hostname then I want it gets read from hosts only.

Comment: You could configure Ansible to set this in the vars. And an IP and hostname do not really differ, if it's a webhost. Again, it's usable in your use-case.

Comment: I added the playbook again.

Answer (score 0):

### I have written this but for webservers group it;s taking hosts as webservers only and not picking up the IP.

- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars_prompt:
- name: "hosts" prompt: "Please enter the host details"
  private: no
- name: "port"
  prompt: "Please enter the port details"
  private: no
  vars:
  sites: - http://{{ hosts }}:{{ port }}/test

tasks:

- name: verify if all urls works properly
  uri:
  url: "{{ item }}"
  timeout: 10
  with_items: "{{ sites }}"
  register: health_check
  ignore_errors: yes

But again this failed with below error.
TASK [verify if all urls works properly] **************************************************************************************** failed: [10.10.10.30] (item=webservers:8080/test) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "content": "", "elapsed": 0, "item": "webservers:8080/test", "msg": "Status code was -1 and not [200]: Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", "redirected": false, "status": -1, "url": "webservers:8080/test"}

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.