# Calling api by proxy takes 15+seconds

Tags: c#, windows, dns, delay

In C # application, when calling API interface, it often takes 15+ seconds to access. API is deployed in another network segment of intranet and needs to be accessed by proxy. Some one said that it was a DNS problem, try to setting the host, which has no effect.
Environment: Windows Server 2012 R2, IIS v8.5
Code Script:

```
  private string PostHttp(string url, string authHeader, string requestBody)
        {
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(CheckValidationResult);

            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";


            System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://myHttpProxyAddress", false);
            proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("HttpProxyUser", "HttpProxyPassword");
        
            webRequest.Proxy = proxy;

            var writer = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            writer.Close();

            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = null;

                if (webResponse.Headers["Content-Encoding"] == "gzip")
                    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(new GZipStream(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                else
                    reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: [FYI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.automaticdecompression?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 0):

it's very difficult to point out by just hearing someone said one of the possibility (e.g DNS error) , try to use some http utility (e.g Curl) to check and measure that.

you can wrap the request above with below this guide and measure the timing detail.

[How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl)

Comment: Thanks for comment.  Here is the trace log in a day: ` [Time] Elasped Time(ms) [14:20:14.5923] :15175
[14:21:18.2560] :147
[14:22:22.1694] :117
[14:47:21.9716] :157
[14:47:52.3604] :106
[15:04:56.1902] :15155
[15:23:00.7822] :161
[15:24:12.0431] :125
[15:45:05.4117] :15149
[15:46:10.0582] :159
[15:46:54.2999] :105
[15:48:21.3480] :114
[16:09:09.8806] :172
[16:09:50.9243] :106
[16:22:59.3809] :15155
[16:23:50.5958] :107
[17:58:28.9433] :15216
[18:01:11.3708] :15113
[18:04:59.2404] :15153
[22:12:52.6497] :15225
[22:13:00.3718] :104`

Comment: you can export that with timing details , and share with your network/infra team that setup the proxy in the server.