# Compare time command result in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I want to check speed of a website with a shell script.
I'm using time format to get number result but I have problem with comparator.
This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEFORMAT=%E
TOTAL=`time wget -pq --no-cache --delete-after -H https://www.netflix.com 2>&1`
echo $TOTAL

if [[ "$TOTAL" -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo 'YES'
else
    echo 'NO'
fi
```

Result was about greather than 2, but result was always no.

EDIT

This is result of script

```
2,119
NO
```

EDIT 2

Thanks, resolved this way

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date +%s)
time wget -pq --no-cache --delete-after -H https://www.netflix.com 2>&1
end=$(date +%s)
total=$(($end-$start))

echo "Elapsed Time: $(($total)) seconds"

if [[ $total -gt 1 ]]; then
    echo 'YES'
else
    echo 'NO'
fi
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #32](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).

Comment: (that said, I wouldn't use `time` for what you're doing here in the first place, particularly if you only need integer granularity; easier to record `SECONDS` before and after the `wget` and compare).

Comment: (,,,and btw, note that POSIX advises you to use lower-case names for your own variables so you don't overwrite a reserved/built-in one by mistake; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable; also, a lot of shell-built-in variables lose their special meaning and become normal variables if you assign to them directly).

Comment: (whereas if you need floating-point evaluation to deal with numbers that _aren't_ integers, bash's built-in math doesn't support it at all, so you need to use the techniques from [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022))

Comment: you should a) update the question to show the complete output from your script and b)  review the contents of `TOTAL` (eg, add `typeset -p TOTAL` after the `TOTAL=$(...)` line); my guess is that `TOTAL` does not contain what you think it contains

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl `-gt 0` - shell does not support floating point

Comment: The value of `$TOTAL` contains a comma as the thousands separator. Arithmetic operations don't understand numbers like this, you need to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `time` command is not really handy to use (for calculations) in a script because you will have to parse through all the output and convert numbers etc. You second version is a better approach and works.

But when you use variables in bash arithmetic functions `$(($end-$start))` you don't have to prefix the variables with a `$`. Also, why do you use `$(($total))` in that `echo`-statement? Just use `$total`.

And as mentioned in a comment I would also use the SHELL built-in `$SECONDS` variable instead of `date` (which will run as a subprocess). You now don't really need the `time` command but it gives you a nice overview of used kernel- and user-mode CPU time which you might want to see.

So the result would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/env bash

start=$SECONDS
time wget -pq --no-cache --delete-after -H https://www.netflix.com 2>&1
end=$SECONDS
total=$((end-start))

echo "Elapsed Time: $total seconds"

if [ $total -gt 1 ]
 then
   echo 'YES'
else
   echo 'NO'
fi
```