# GCP Load Balancer + Cloud Run: Where is extra latency coming from?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a Cloud Run service. It uses Redis extensively yet I cannot get request latencies below 100ms:

[image]

When I run locally, latencies are sub-10ms. If I check logs, Cloud Run is also reporting sub 10ms latency:

[image]

What gives? Cloud Run is behind a load balancer, so my conclusion is that the load balancer is introducing this latency. Any way to debug this or am I just at GCP's mercy? It's a global load balancer, Cloud Run service is in `us-central1`, I'm in Idaho.

Comment: Are you accounting for cold start time of the Cloud Run container?

Comment: Yes, this is using warm containers. No matter how many times I refresh, latency of requests is >100ms, often >150ms

Comment: Have you tried checking out this? https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tutorials/optimize-app-latency

Comment: Do you use a load balancer or do you use raw Cloud Run service (which has its own LB)? Did you perform a CURL request with statistic (to know the different duration of your request on the client side)?

Comment: Please provide details on how you are testing. What does "testing locally" mean, for example? Your problem description does not have enough details to know the solution. Suggestion: use the CLI `curl` to time requests. Then test with the load balancer endpoint and then with the Cloud Run endpoint. Cloud Run has two endpoints (managed DNS and service generated), which one are you using for the load balancer NEG? This SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625150/8016720) shows how to time requests with curl.