# How do I get a server's response time?

Tags: ruby

How can I get a server response time with ruby?

Im using `Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))` to the response code and response time of the URL. Actually my code is:

```
start_time = Time.now
@req = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
end_time = (Time.now - start_time) * 1000
puts ("%.2f" % end_time + "ms")
```

Is working perfectly, but I'm getting too high response times, e.g.: Twitter.com (630.52ms). If I try to ping twitter.com, I'm getting 70/120ms of response.

Is this the best way to calculate the response time of this server?

Comment: Could you provide an SSCCE?  You are very close.  http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Define “server response time”.

Answer (score 2):

What you implemented does not show the server response time, it shows:

- the time spent in ruby to send the request
- the network time of the request
- the server's response time
- the network time of the response
- the time spent in ruby to process the response

If you need to see only the time that the server took to process the request you need to do it with another way. You can use the `HTTP` [response headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Responses). The date header in particular can help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby timings are included in your version of code as [@xlembouras](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21974110/4950680) said.

I would suggest to use `curl` for what you are looking for:

```
response_time_total = `curl -w \"%{time_total}\" google.com -o /dev/null -s`
```

You can try it out in terminal:

```
curl -w \"%{time_total}\n\" google.com -o /dev/null -s
```

There are different metrics you can get like `time_namelookup`, `time_connect`, `time_starttransfer`, `time_redirect`, etc. Example:

```
response_times = `curl -w \"%{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}\" google.com -o /dev/null -s`
time_connect, time_starttransfer, time_total = response_times.split(':')
```

All available metrics and detailed information can be found at [the cURL manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Refs

[How do I measure request and response times at once using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215389/how-do-i-measure-request-and-response-times-at-once-using-curl)